# Should function object be an function argument or its reference?

Tags: c++

I use the following example to illustrate my question:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


class TestOperator
{
public:
    TestOperator(float k):k_(k){};

    ~TestOperator() {};

    float operator() (float m, float s)
    {
        return (1-k_)*m+k_*m*0.0078*s;
    }
private:
    float k_;

};

template<typename Operator>
void perform(Operator fun)
{
    int value;
    value = fun(3.1f,2.5f);

}

template<typename Operator>
void perform2(Operator &fun)
{
    int value;
    value = fun(3.1f,2.5f);

}


int main()
{

    TestOperator myOperator(0.1f);
    perform(myOperator);


    perform2(myOperator);

   return 0;
}
```

In `perform` we are using function object as function argument wile in `perform2` we are using function object reference as function argument. In the tutorials on function objects, the former usage is dominant like this tutorial [function objects](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html). Then my question is: why do not use function object reference? For me, it is better. Any ideas?

Comment: Need a copy...pass by value. Don't need a copy...pass by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function objects (or functors) that have members in their structure will be copied when passed by value, and not copied when passed by reference.

In  your example, the member k_ would "survive" through a call by reference, as in perform2. If for some reason there was information retained, and not initialized, in the functor, this could have curious side effects.

It would be possible to use pass by reference to collect and retain information within the functor from one usage to the next.

If passed by value, the copies used would evaporate upon return, and the information between calls is lost.

Put another way, the original functor, myOperator, is unchanged by perform, but it IS changed by perform2.

You could provide a const myOperator to perform, but not to perform2 as declared. If you declared perform2 as taking a const &, it would not compile because the function in the functor is not const (not guaranteed to NOT change things in the functor).

Which is 'better' is not known. One is more applicable than the other in some situations, the copy being "safer" and more widely applicable, if theoretically slower.

Answer (score 1):

My guideline:

Use `Operator fun` in most cases.

Use `Operator& fun` only if `fun` has data that should not be copied from one invocation of the `operaor()` to the next. E.g. if `Operator` is used gather data that it holds in a container, it will be necessary to pass `fun` by reference.